# Prime numbers between given two numbers in Julia and Python comparison

Tags: python, julia

See the Python code for finding prime numbers between given two numbers lower and upper:

```
lower = 3
upper = 15

print("Prime numbers between", lower, "and", upper, "are:")

for num in range(lower, upper + 1):

   for i in range(2, num):
       if (num % i) == 0:
           break
   else:
       print(num)
```

Python Output:

```
Prime numbers between 3 and 15 are:
3
5
7
11
13
```

Almost similar code in Julia gives incorrect output. See the Julia code below:

```
lower = 3
upper = 15
println("Prime numbers between ", lower, " and “, upper, " are:”)
for num in lower:upper    
    for i in 2: num-1
        if (num % i) == 0
            break           
        else
            println(num)
            break
        end
    end
end
```

Julia Output:

```
Prime numbers between 3 and 15 are:
3
5
7
9
11
13
15
```

Clearly, 9 and 15 are not primes. Why does Python code gives correct output and Julia code does not. Any way to fix it using the same algorithmic logic?

Comment: Looks like the Julia `else` is connected to the `if`, not the `for`.

Comment: python does `for/else`, julia does `if/else`, Julia has no such, use a variable to mark that you pass the break

Comment: Some recommendations: 1) You do not need to check even numbers. 2) You do not need to check from 2 until the number itself. You need to check until `sqrt(number) + 1`.

Comment: for/while-else in Python allows you to more simply write "if `break` didn't end this loop, do this afterward". It is very rarely taught or used, and during an email discussion about its issues (how it can be confused with if-else, useless else if no `break` is written), Python's creator clarifies that he would NOT include for/while-else if he could redesign Python, though he does not support changing the `else` keyword and does not think keeping it is so problematic. https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-ideas/2009-October/006157.html

Comment: @MarkRansom: Which is immediately obvious from the indentation even within the OP's own code.

Comment: @JörgWMittag I don't know enough about Julia to know if indentation is significant like it is in Python.

Comment: @MarkRansom: It is not, but it is clear that the author of the code knows that the `else` does not belong to the `for`, otherwise, they wouldn't have indented it this way. When Landin introduced indentation-based syntax in ISWIM, the idea was that programmers use indentation *anyway* to indicate nesting (and mathematicians had done so long before that), so why not get rid of the symbols that indicate nesting?

Answer (score 15):

Here is the code I would use that keeps the same algorithmic logic per your request (I write this code this way as the condition inside the loop is not only efficient but also reads naturally: "either any of the numbers from the range `2:num-1` divides `num` or print `num`"):

```
julia> lower = 3
3

julia> upper = 15
15

julia> println("Prime numbers between $lower and $upper are:")
Prime numbers between 3 and 15 are:

julia> for num in lower:upper
           any(i -> num % i == 0, 2:num-1) || println(num)
       end
3
5
7
11
13
```

Per comments to your question in Julia you do not have `else` clause in `for` loop.
However using the `any` function keeps the same logic as your code as it is a short-circuting function (achieving the same effect as `break` in your for loop).

If anything is not clear in my code please let me know.

---

EDIT:

I will rewrite the code to explain how it works.

First the `||` part. It uses the [short-circuting](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/control-flow/#man-conditional-evaluation) behavior of `||` operator. So on the first level this can be rewritten as:

```
julia> lower = 3
3

julia> upper = 15
15

julia> println("Prime numbers between $lower and $upper are:")
Prime numbers between 3 and 15 are:

julia> for num in lower:upper
           iscomposite = any(i -> num % i == 0, 2:num-1)
           if !iscomposite
               println(num)
           end
       end
3
5
7
11
13
```

Now, as commented `any` is doing short circuting also so it is equivalent to writing:

```
julia> lower = 3
3

julia> upper = 15
15

julia> println("Prime numbers between $lower and $upper are:")
Prime numbers between 3 and 15 are:

julia> for num in lower:upper
           iscomposite = false
           for i in 2:num-1
               if num % i == 0
                   iscomposite = true
                   break
               end
           end
           if !iscomposite
               println(num)
           end
       end
3
5
7
11
13
```

Comment: wonderful and succinct code but can you please explain the logic contained in for loop in more detail.  what is  the role of || operator. Thanks for responding. I am new to Julia and your help is really appreciated

Comment: The `||` here is an abbreviated conditional. Basically it is the same as 
`if !any(...) something`. This works because the `||` short-circuits if the `any(...)` is true. This is also commonly done with `&&` to do error checking with `condition(...) && error("foo blew out")`.

Answer (score 3):

Your Julia code seems to print inside and break the factor checking loop instead of waiting for all factors to be verified. (I don't know Julia but that seems to be an obvious difference).

Comment: My code implements exactly the same logic as the Python code of OP. I will expand on it in my answer.

Comment: It still prints the number after checking only the first factor. So anything not divisible by 2 will be printed by the Julia code.  The Python code's else: statement pertains to the for loop (not the if) so it only executes when the loop is not stopped by the inner break.  (so not the same logic)

Comment: Your assumption how Julia works is incorrect. Have you tried running the Julia code? Only prime numbers are printed. The tested number is printed printed only if it is is not divisible by any numbers less than it.

Comment: Thanks Bogumil Kaminski for a more detailed explanation